# Multiple Formulas in a cell with IF condition

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to figure out how I can insert multiple formulas in a single cell. The calculation pertains to date & time.

Below is my questions.

If A1 = Date & B1 = Time (military) **AND** C1=Date and D1=Time (military), to get the difference in time, in hours, I am using the below formula, in F1.

```
=((C1+D1)-(A1+B1))*24
```

What I need to do is to for F1 to determine if there is no value in A1 & B1 than use the `=now()` function to complete the formula. In other words, I need the following formula to kick in.

```
=(now()-(A1+B1))*24
```

or something of this sort.

I am beginner with Excel and need this to create a time measurement report.

Answer (score 1):

The first question is: exactly what condition do you want to test for? 
I think you want

```
OR(ISBLANK(C1), ISBLANK(D1))
```

or

```
OR(C1="", D1="")
```

which mean almost the same thing — that either `C1` or `D1` is blank. 
Other possibilities include

- `AND(ISBLANK(C1), ISBLANK(D1))`

  or

  `AND(C1="", D1="")`
- `ISBLANK(C1)`

  or

  `C1=""`

  with the expectation that a blank `D1` will be treated as `00:00`.
- `(C1+D1)=0`

  which is pretty much equivalent to `AND(C1="", D1="")`.

Once you’ve chosen your condition, the `IF` function is fairly easy. 
The “brute force” solution would be

```
=IF(OR(C1="",D1=""), (NOW()-(A1+B1))*24, ((C1+D1)-(A1+B1))*24)
```

But you can move the common parts outside:

```
=(IF(OR(C1="",D1=""), NOW(), C1+D1) - (A1+B1)) *24
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel is already perfectly capable of storing dates and times exactly as you need them to be - you shouldn't need to multiply things out by 24 etc. If you just `format` cells as Dates or Times then they'll show as hours and minutes automatically (1.0 = 24h, 0.5 = 12h etc)

But I think the formula you're looking for should be:

`=IF((A1+B1)>0,now()-A1+B1,0)`

This formula tests to see if the total of A1 and B1 is greater than zero, and then returns your formula. Otherwise, it returns zero. If you've formatted the cell to show time, then this zero can show as 00:00, which appears to be what you're asking for.